# C# - Replace Every UpperCase Letter with Underscore and the Letter

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

How do replace Every UpperCase Letter with Underscore and the Letter in C#?
note: unless the character is already proceeded by a underscore.

**UPDATE:**
For example, 
MikeJones
would be turned into
Mike_Jones

But Mike_Jones
would not be turned into
Mike__Jones

Is Regex the best approach? Where do I start with this one?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide an example of what you mean? ie the string looks like this but after doing what I want would look like this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Regex sounds best:

```
string input = "Test_StringForYou";
string replaced = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!_)([A-Z])", "_$1");
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

Output: _Test_String_For_You

Be sure to add a `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Comment: +1 - is there a way to alter the Regex so the first letter has no underscore in front?

Comment: @tyndall: `(?<!_|^)([A-Z])` or maybe `(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])` should do it.

Comment: What about the reverse operation ?

Answer (score 3):

So you *don't* want to change the case of the letters!  I know you didn't say you did, but some of us assumed it because that question comes up so often.  In that case, this regex is all you need:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", @"_$1");
```

Doing the positive lookbehind for a lowercase letter also ensures that you don't add an underscore to the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(subject, "([A-Z])", "_$1");
```

changes The Quick Brown Fox to _The _Quick _Brown _Fox

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to transform this:

> Sample Text

Into

> _sample _text

Then no, RegEx won't strictly do that, as you can't transform captures or groups in the replacement expression. You could, of course, use Jake's answer and add a `.ToLower()` call to the end, which would replace all capital letters with lowercase letters.

If all you're looking to do is prepend an underscore to every capital letter that doesn't already have one, then Jake's answer alone should do the trick.

Comment: Wrong. You can (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @Kenny: It's not wrong, as the RegEx syntax doesn't allow for transformations. The *API* does, in this case, but not the syntax itself. For this example, I think calling `ToLower()` is likely to result in clearer, simpler code.

Comment: Then the RegEx syntax doesn't allow replacement either. But I agree scanning the string and use `.ToLower()` is much better than RegEx in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------

string str = Regex.Replace("MyString", @"([A-Z])", " $1").Trim();

//-----------------------------------------------------------------

str givs "My String"
```

It's working nice

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is still relevent, but here is a simple way to do it.

```
private string StripInput(string input)
    {
        var output = input
            .Replace(" ", "_")
            .ToLower().Trim();
        return output;
    }

string TEST = "Hello World";
    litTest.Text = StripInput(TEST);
```

Will come out as: hello_world

Comment: This does not replace every uppercase letter with an underscore **and** the letter. It replaces spaces with an underscore and makes everything lowercase.